# Append value to line in input file based on column number

Tags: shell, awk

I have a function `append_val_to_line` which appends the `$append_val` to the line in *Input.txt* and writes it back. I want to insert `45` at column 1 and it should and since its length is two values, it should at it at column 1 and column 0. But my code below is adding it at column 2 and column 3.

I am not sure why it is so. Can someone help me achieve the goal mentioned above?

My working solution is below but it does not add the `45` at column 0 and 1. I want a generic solution as I can insert the value at any column and the value should be added starting at *column N* to *column N-1 ... N-2* based on the length of the `append_val`.

As you can see in the sample input before and sample input after the call to `append_val_to_line` function, the value `45` is added at column 1 and column 2 but I wanted to the from column 0 and end on column 1 as the value 45 is of length two. But my code adds it starting at column 2 and 3 instead.

Space is also a valid column number but I will not be adding any values in those spaces in a line.

```
#! /bin/bash

function append_val_to_line{
    sed -i 's/\(.\{'$1'\}\)/\1'$2'/' "input.txt"
}

column_num=1
append_val=45

append_vals_to_line "$column_num" "$append_val"
```

*Input.txt* BEFORE call to function `append_vals_to_line`

```
1200    5600   775000   34555
```

*Input.txt* AFTER call to function `append_vals_to_line`

```
145200    5600   775000   34555
```

Note 45 has been added at column 2 and 3.

Comment: Could you please do let us know what are the conditions to get your expected output as its not clear as of now in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 As you can see in the sample input before call to append_val_to_line and sample input after the call, the value ```45``` is added at column 1 and column 2 but I wanted to the start from column 0 and end on column 1 as the value ```45``` is of length two. But my code adds it starting at column 2 and 3 instead.

Comment: There is confusion I believe, columns will be considered with space as delimiter between them, that's why its not clear how you how are you considering columns?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Space is also a valid column number but I will not be adding any values in those spaces in a line. Is there any other confusion you have?

Comment: after fixing some syntax issues I was able to get the code to generate '451200    5600   ....` by setting `column_num=0`; what am I missing?; if the OP really wants to start column numbering with `1` then how about having the function subtract `1` from the input parameter so the `sed` command works as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OP told OP wants to start character's position from `0` and I believe rather than column its character's position number which we are talking about here, so based on that and shown samples following may help then.

```
awk -v after="0" -v value="45" '{print substr($0,1,after+1) value substr($0,after+2)}' Input_file
```

Non one liner form of above:

```
awk -v after="0" -v value="45" '
{
  print substr($0,1,after+1) value substr($0,after+2)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above one.

```
awk -v after="0" -v value="45" '                          ##Start awk prorgam from heer and setting after variable to 0 a per OP and value to 45.
{
  print substr($0,1,after+1) value substr($0,after+2)     ##Printing sub-string from 1 to till after+1 value since OP wants to insert value to 2nd character so printing 1st character here. Then I a printing value here, then printing rest of the current Line.
}
'  Input_file                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It is actually column number 1 rather than character position. In shell, a file starts from column 1. May you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: @Anna, In `awk` default delimiter is space so by keeping that in mind I written that. IMHO this solution should work for you, could you please check it once and lemme know? We could discuss more on column and character position part too :)

Comment: How do I write the contents back to same input file instead of printing it? and can the after=# be modifiable to have it at any column number?

Comment: @Anna, please change `Input_file` in my solution to `Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` and that should save output into Input_file itself, lemme know how it goes?

Comment: I am testing it right now and it looks good, will update in few mins. thanks alot :)

Comment: What is the meaning of $0 in the substr method?

Comment: @Anna, `$0` means whole current line and `substr`is `awk` function to get sub-string, lemme add a detailed explanation in few mins here.

Comment: I just had one more question, is there like an abs() method which I can put around the ```after-1``` to make sure the diff is always positive?

Comment: @Anna,I added detailed explanation now. For your function thing sorry I didn't get it could you please explain it more.